# Opening a .PS from command line

Tags: ghostscript, csh, postscript

I want to open a .PS (postscript file) having produced it from a .csh script running a series of GMT commands preferably using ghostview. I am trying:

```
gv plot.ps
```

This however opens ghostview but not my plot. Instead I just get the spinning wheel. The plot itself can however be opened through the file viewer and is fully functional.

I have been looking at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310397/i-want-to-view-a-ps-file-through-ghostscript-9-05-command-prompt

which suggests:

```
GS> (c:/Users/Ankit/Desktop/abc.ps)
```

But this also does not work for me.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

While gv is a venerable and classic postscript viewer, it is not standard installed in Ubuntu 16.04. Did you try evince?

> evince plot.ps &

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) (PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer) simply launch it form the command line like this:

```
gs plot.ps
```